# Is my contractor right about my noisy bathroom tiles?

Tags: tile, subfloor, grout

[image]I posted about this yesterday too under a different username but can’t figure out how to just update it and so I’m doing a new post after gathering some more info. Apologies if that’s annoying.

I noticed when stepping on some of my new hexagonal ceramic bathroom tiles, installed less than a year ago, that a couple of them were making a single popping noise, almost as if a marble was being dropped. On closer inspection it seemed like the grout was cracked.

The contractor came and said he wasn’t sure why it was popping but didn’t think it needed repairs, just one of those things. He said that actually the grout wasn’t cracked; some was just stuck to the beveled edge of one side of the tile, and indeed with the scrape of his thumb he made it look like new. (Is this a thing? It did work. The image is the before picture.) When hitting with hammer, the affected tiles don’t sound hollow or anything. His theory is that perhaps something under the tiles, in the wood beneath, is popping, but I should monitor for it to get worse. I have my warranty with him for another few months.

He said he did everything right — new plywood subfloor nailed down every 6 inches (same as tiles), an underpayment, and Schluter Ditra, with each tile back buttered and carefully put in place with the right thinset.

Is he right to NOT be worried much about it? I don’t mind living with a bit of noise from my floor if it doesn’t get worse, it’s already noisy elsewhere as it’s an old house, but wondering if I should press him to address it or if based on these facts there’s any hint about what happened.

Comment: See[I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) Ref: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/285023/are-tile-popping-sounds-grout-cracks-signs-of-subfloor-problems [which is an unregistered account]

Comment: Does the tile move?  Tiles do not flex, they crack.  Tiles and movement do not mix.

Comment: Go back to whatever browser you posted from yesterday - the cookies for your non-registered account should still be there. Register your account, then edit.

Comment: All the contractor actions sound correct, but we don’t know what your floor joists are (span, spacing, depth of joist). It could just be that you have a bouncy floor.

Comment: Aloysius, agree that could be an issue. If it is, am I up a creek? Or is it just meh, it’ll sound a little weird, like squeaky stairs. Like, how big a problem is that? It’s an old house.

Comment: I fixed a clicky (well, more crunchy in my case) tile in an old chicago apt  with a hot air gun and a candle; heated the tile up hot, melted wax into the seam, cleaned up while warm. Once the wax in the crack cooled it prevented the motion and stopped the noise.